# Distinct values with XSLT 1.0 when XPath has multiple criteria

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, distinct, xpath-1.0

Yet another question about getting distinct values using XSLT 1.0. Here's a stupid, made-up example that should illustrate my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<moviesByYear>
    <year1994>
        <movie>
            <genre>Action</genre>
            <director>A</director>
        </movie>
    </year1994>
    <year1994>
        <movie>
            <genre>Comedy</genre>
            <director>A</director>
        </movie>
    </year1994>
    <year1994>
        <movie>
            <genre>Drama</genre>
            <director>B</director>
        </movie>
    </year1994>
    <year1994>
        <movie>
            <genre>Thriller</genre>
            <director>C</director>
        </movie>
    </year1994>
    <year1995>
        <movie>
            <genre>Action</genre>
            <director>A</director>
        </movie>
    </year1995>
    <year1995>
        <movie>
            <genre>Comedy</genre>
            <director>C</director>
        </movie>
    </year1995>
    <year1996>
        <movie>
            <genre>Thriller</genre>
            <director>A</director>
        </movie>
    </year1996>
</moviesByYear>
```

Now let's say that I'd like to list all years that produced movies that are either comedies or directed by director B. I use the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/moviesByYear/*[movie/genre='Comedy' or movie/director='B']">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives me the following output:

```
year1994year1994year1995
```

I have not yet found any solution for getting distinct values that would work here. For example, using `name(.) != name(following-sibling::*)` causes `year1994` to be excluded altogether.

In my real-world case I have a complex XML structure and an XPath with many criteria that picks out a number of nodes, from which I need to get an output of distinct node names.

**Update:** michael.hor257k gave an elegant solution to this, but using it I faced a problem with xsl:key. Allow me to alter the scenario a bit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <genres>
        <genre>Action</genre>
        <genre>Comedy</genre>
        <genre>Drama</genre>
        <genre>Thriller</genre>
    </genres>
    <moviesByYear>
        <year1994>
            <movie>
                <genre>Action</genre>
                <director>A</director>
            </movie>
        </year1994>
        <year1994>
            <movie>
                <genre>Comedy</genre>
                <director>A</director>
            </movie>
        </year1994>
        <year1994>
            <movie>
                <genre>Drama</genre>
                <director>B</director>
            </movie>
        </year1994>
        <year1994>
            <movie>
                <genre>Thriller</genre>
                <director>C</director>
            </movie>
        </year1994>
        <year1995>
            <movie>
                <genre>Action</genre>
                <director>A</director>
            </movie>
        </year1995>
        <year1995>
            <movie>
                <genre>Comedy</genre>
                <director>C</director>
            </movie>
        </year1995>
        <year1996>
            <movie>
                <genre>Thriller</genre>
                <director>A</director>
            </movie>
        </year1996>
    </moviesByYear>
</root>
```

Now let's say that I want a list of genres, each of which lists years that produced movies of that genre or movies directed by director B. Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/genres/genre">
        <xsl:call-template name="output">
            <xsl:with-param name="genre">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:param name="director" select="'B'"/>

<xsl:key name="year" match="year" use="." />

<xsl:template name="output">
    <xsl:param name="genre"/>

    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="years">
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/moviesByYear/*/movie[genre=$genre or director=$director]"> 
            <year><xsl:value-of select="local-name(..)"/></year>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="years-set" select="exsl:node-set($years)" />

    <!-- final pass -->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($genre, ': ')"/> 
    <xsl:for-each select="$years-set/year[count(. | key('year', .)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces the following output:

```
Action: year1994year1995
Comedy: 
Drama: 
Thriller: year1996
```

As you can see, each year is listed only once. The desired output would have been:

```
Action: year1994year1995
Comedy: year1994year1995
Drama: year1994
Thriller: year1994year1996
```

Comment: You should find out if your processor supports the EXSLT set:distinct() function; that would make this much easier.

Comment: I'm using MSXML6. Seems like it doesn't support that function.
http://www.exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/

Comment: That page hasn't been updated in years - you should consult your processor's documentation. I believe MS also have a set of their own extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a different implementation of Muenchian grouping - one that allows you to *parametrize* the criteria by which the movies are selected.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="genre" select="'Comedy'"/>
<xsl:param name="director" select="'B'"/>

<xsl:key name="year" match="year" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/">

    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="years">
        <xsl:for-each select="moviesByYear/*/movie[genre=$genre or director=$director]"> 
            <year><xsl:value-of select="local-name(..)"/></year>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="years-set" select="exsl:node-set($years)" />

    <!-- final pass -->
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="$years-set/year[count(. | key('year', .)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the above is applied to your example input, the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <year>year1994</year>
   <year>year1995</year>
</output>
```

---

### Edit:

With regard to your modified input, I believe I would do it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="director" select="'B'"/>

<xsl:key name="movies-by-genre" match="movie" use="genre" />
<xsl:key name="movies-by-director" match="movie" use="director" />
<xsl:key name="year" match="year" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root/genres/genre"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="genre">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="years">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('movies-by-genre', .) | key('movies-by-director', $director)"> 
            <year><xsl:value-of select="local-name(..)"/></year>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="years-set" select="exsl:node-set($years)" />
    <!-- final pass -->
    <genre name="{.}">
        <xsl:for-each select="$years-set/year[count(. | key('year', .)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </genre>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result here is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <genre name="Action">
      <year>year1994</year>
      <year>year1995</year>
   </genre>
   <genre name="Comedy">
      <year>year1994</year>
      <year>year1995</year>
   </genre>
   <genre name="Drama">
      <year>year1994</year>
   </genre>
   <genre name="Thriller">
      <year>year1994</year>
      <year>year1996</year>
   </genre>
</output>
```

Note: the two added keys are for efficiency only - they are not required for the main purpose here.

---

### Edit 2:

On second thought, we could do this all in a single pass, thus (hopefully) avoiding the issues Xalan and MSXSML have with processing a variable - but still using Muenchian grouping:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="director" select="'B'"/>

<xsl:key name="year" match="moviesByYear/*" use="local-name()" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root/genres/genre"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="genre">
    <xsl:variable name="genre" select="." />
    <genre name="{$genre}">
        <xsl:for-each select="../../moviesByYear/* 
        [count(. | key('year', local-name())[1]) = 1]
        [key('year', local-name())/movie[genre=$genre or director=$director]]">
            <year>
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
            </year>  
        </xsl:for-each>
    </genre>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This sure was an elegant solution, but my real-world case apparently needed another thing to take into consideration. Please take a look at the update to my question. Can a key for example somehow be flushed between for-each iterations?

Comment: Hmm. That stylesheet gave me the following output:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <output>
     <genre name="Action">
      <year>year1994</year>
      <year>year1995</year>
     </genre>
     <genre name="Comedy"/>
     <genre name="Drama"/>
     <genre name="Thriller">
      <year>year1996</year>
     </genre>
    </output>

Comment: Seems like only Saxon 6.5.5 gave the desired output there. Xalan 2.7.1 excluded year1995 for Comedy.
Sorry about the ugly comment. Quite inconvenient that only questions/answers support code blocks. I can see that you can do `inline code`, but that doesn't help if you want to show a small piece of XML output.

Comment: @Ingo88 Hm. This is an interesting bug. I am getting the correct result in both libxslt and Saxon - it's only Xalan that fails in the final Muenchian grouping. Are you having the same problem with your MSXML processor?

Comment: MSXML6 gives the output I pasted into my comment above, ie. it outputs each year only once. Weird how it works differently between engines. The only difference in the stylsheet itself is that I needed to change this namespace declaration: `xmlns:exsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"`.

Comment: @Ingo88 I am afraid those are bugs and therefore beyond my competence. If your processor doesn't support set:distinct(), you will have to give up on Muenchian grouping and resort to the primitive method of comparing each year to its preceding siblings.

Comment: What do you mean by "Or not"?

Comment: @Ingo88 I mean I have edited my answer to show how this can be done with Muenchian grouping nevertheless.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that. Indeed this solution worked! Excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml:

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="moviesByYear/*[movie/genre='Comedy' or movie/director='B']" use="local-name()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/moviesByYear/*[movie/genre='Comedy' or movie/director='B'][generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', local-name())[1])]">
            <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think you have made it too easy on yourself by hard-coding the criteria into the key definition. I will post another answer that removes this limitation.

Answer (score 3):

Now, just because it was said it couldn't be done, here's an XPath one-liner:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="genre" select="'Comedy'"/>
<xsl:param name="director" select="'B'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="//movie[genre=$genre or director=$director] 
        [not(local-name(..)=local-name(preceding::movie[genre=$genre or director=$director]/parent::*))]">
            <year>       
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name(..)"/>
            </year>  
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Not recommended for efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="moviesByYear/*[movie/genre='Comedy' or movie/director='B'][not(name(.) = following-sibling::*[movie/genre='Comedy' or movie/director='B']/name(.))]">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Does it work for *you*? (that's a rhetorical question - it's invalid code.)

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, It worked for me with saxon9.jar but not with saxon6. I suspected it to be a bug in jar. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You cannot use an expression like `item/name()` in XSLT 1.0 (it does work in XSLT 2.0). In any case, this is not a good approach overall - read the article mentioned in Martin Honnen's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do that w/ a straight xpath expression. The only way I can see to do this is using an XSLT variable (or in my example a template parameter).

What this code is doing is in the for-each loop in the master template the XPATH `/moviesByYear/*[name(.) != name(following-sibling::*)]` selects the last instance of each child year, so that the node-set only contains 1 element for each year. We don't care whether that element is going to match our actual criteria or not, we just care about its name.

The we stuff that name in the parameter to the named `foo` template, which uses that name to select all matching elements but only of that year and then select the 1st of those `/moviesByYear/*[name(.) = $year][movie/genre='Comedy' or movie/director='B'][1]`. If we find that 1 matching element we output the name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/moviesByYear/*[name(.) != name(following-sibling::*)]">
    <xsl:call-template name="foo">
      <xsl:with-param name="year" select="name(.)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="foo">
 <xsl:param name="year" select="'year1994'" />
 <xsl:for-each select="/moviesByYear/*[name(.) = $year][movie/genre='Comedy' or movie/director='B'][1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This template when run against your test date produces the output:

```
year1994year1995
```