# XSL Removing Empty Elements After Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to write an extensive XSLT that doesn't output (removes) any element that is empty. For Attributes, this means that if the value of the path is empty, it will not populate that attribute in the output. For Nodes, this means that if there isn't any data (empty attributes or child nodes without attributes/data) it will not populate that node in the output. Below is an example related to Baseball to better explain what I'm looking for.

How the output looks like now:

```
  <Baseball>
    <Fields>
      <Equipment>
        <Bats>
          <Bat Brand="Louisville" Model="16534" Length="34" Weight="30" Description="Composite" />
          <Bat Brand="Easton" Model="asdfer" Length="32" Weight="29" Description="" />
          <Bat Brand="" Model="" Length="" Weight="" Description="" />
        </Bats>
        <Gloves>
          <Glove Brand="" Model="" Length="" Description="" />
        </Gloves>
      </Equipment>
    </Fields>
  </Baseball>
```

How I need the output to look like:

```
<Baseball>
    <Fields>
      <Equipment>
        <Bats>
          <Bat Brand="Louisville" Model="16534" Length="34" Weight="30" Description="Composite" />
          <Bat Brand="Easton" Model="asdfer" Length="32" Weight="29" />
        </Bats>
      </Equipment>
    </Fields>
  </Baseball>
```

I know I can solve this issue by writing  to check the value but given the length of the transformation, I would like to avoid this if at all possible. In addition, give the structure of the XML that I will be drawing from, attributes for a given output node will have paths that differentiate from each other. For Example, the attribute "Brand" in the output node "Bat" might have a path of "ab/cd/ef/brand" while the attribute "Model" might have a path "ab/wx/yz/model". (I know my Baseball example above is not conducive to this point). Is there a way to achieve this without writing two XSLTs? Can you pass back through the output in XSLT?

Comment: No way to do a second pass with a single transform, but you can write your XSLT to cope with the problem in a neat way... do you have an example of the input XML so we can demonstrate?

Comment: @JohnLBevan "*No way to do a second pass with a single transform*" Not sure what you mean by that. You certainly **can** make multiple passes within the same transform (stylesheet). You will find numerous examples of this, here's just the first one I picked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205393/distinct-values-with-xslt-1-0-when-xpath-has-multiple-criteria/24216212#24216212

Comment: @michael.hor257k - In the example shown there aren't multiple passes of the document.  The data's loaded into a variable which is then manipulated, but there isn't some template setup to match on elements generated by a different template which matches on the original document.

Comment: @JohnLBevan You are either mistaken about that or I am not capable of seeing the distinction you are making. There's no reason why you could not process nodes generated by a template (or set of templates) and stored in a variable by applying another template (or set of templates) to them.

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to make two passes in order to achieve your goal. You just need to add templates to your existing stylesheet that will match the nodes that do not carry information and suppress them.

Since you haven't shown us your existing stylesheet, the following example applies only the *identity transform* to the input as default, while two additional templates eliminate the empty nodes/branches:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- prune the tree -->    
<xsl:template match="*[not(descendant::text() or descendant-or-self::*/@*[string()])]"/>
<xsl:template match="@*[not(string())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your current output as a test input, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Baseball>
   <Fields>
      <Equipment>
         <Bats>
            <Bat Brand="Louisville" Model="16534" Length="34" Weight="30" Description="Composite"/>
            <Bat Brand="Easton" Model="asdfer" Length="32" Weight="29"/>
         </Bats>
      </Equipment>
   </Fields>
</Baseball>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe testing the string-length of descendent attributes? Like this:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="1.0">
        <xsl:template match="*">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(descendant-or-self::*/@*) > 0">
                    <xsl:if test="string-length(descendant-or-self::*/@*) > 0">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                    </xsl:copy>    
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="@*">
            <xsl:if test="string-length(.) > 0">
                <xsl:copy/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

NOTE: This only test the length of the attributes' content, not actual node text. There was none in the sample and you can expand the testing.